# Error "cannot connect to Docker daemon" in the ubuntu docker container

Tags: docker, docker-container, docker-image, docker-desktop, ubuntu-22.04

I am a newbie to docker and I am performing the following steps

1. Installed docker-desktop on windows
2. Pulled the image "ubuntu" (tag is "jammy")
3. Created the container from the above image
4. Tried to pull the 'hello-world' docker image with the command (docker `pull hello-world`)

This gives me the following error

```
Using default tag: latest
**Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?**
```

I tried to run the command `docker version` and it gave me the following output

```
Client:
 Version:           20.10.12
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.17.3
 Git commit:        20.10.12-0ubuntu4
 Built:             Mon Mar  7 17:10:06 2022
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

I then tried the command `sudo service docker start` but it gives me the below error

```
docker: unrecognized service
```

I am stuck here and am trying to find a way to make the docker commands work in my ubuntu docker container. Please help me in understanding what is going wrong and how to resolve it.

Ubuntu version on the container:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy
```

Note 1: I have used the `sudo` also for all the above commands but still the same result.

Note 2: I have also enabled `Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS` option in the docker desktop and restarted my pc

Comment: Especially if you're new to Docker, don't try to run `docker` commands from inside a container.  It's a complicated setup with some significant security implications (it's all but trivial to root the entire host with a `docker run` command).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @DavidMaze, will keep this in mind going forward, but in this case i have no choice. I need a linux environment for me and i choose to go with the docker container